# How to check empty value in a string?

Tags: apex, string

I have array with list of class.

```
public class filterField {
    public String label {get;set;}
    public String searchFieldName {get;set;}
    public String searchValue {get;set;}

    public filterField(String a,String b,String  c) {
        this.label=a;
        this.searchFieldName =b;
        this.searchValue  =c;
    }

}  

public filterField [] filterArray {get;set;}
filterArray = new filterField[]{};
```

FilterArray is list of class. I try to get the value of class string values. I tried below.

apex:

```
for(integer i=0;i<filterArray.size();i++) {
    system.debug('value insude for:::::'+filterArray.get(i).searchValue);

    string s=filterArray.get(i).searchValue;

    if(filterArray.get(i).searchValue!=null || filterArray.get(i).searchValue!='') {

        system.debug('value ins:::::'+filterArray.get(i).searchValue);
        String strField=filterArray.get(i).searchFieldName +':'+'"'+filterArray.get(i).searchValue+'"';
        strFilterField+=strField;
    }
}
```

My array values are :

```
filterField:[label=AccountName, searchFieldName=FULL_NAME, searchValue=], 
filterField:[label=City, searchFieldName=PRIM_CITY, searchValue=test], 
filterField:[label=Country, searchFieldName=PRIM_COUNTRY_NM, searchValue=], 
filterField:[label=Street Address, searchFieldName=PRIM_ADDR_LN_1, searchValue=], 
filterField:[label=State/Province, searchFieldName=PRIM_STATE, searchValue=test], 
filterField:[label=Zip/PostalCode, searchFieldName=PRIM_POSTAL_CD, searchValue=]
```

Comment: String.isBlank(someString);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `String.isBlank(yourString)` to check if it's `null` or `''` or `' '`. This method detects whether string has null or blank space or just quotes.

Example:

```
String str = 'searchValue';
System.assertEquals(false,String.isBlank(str));   // returns false since string is not blank
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.isEmpty(yourString);` 
isEmpty method will also help in checking.

Comment: Important to not the different is that this method does NOT detect a sting containing only whitespace when compared to isBlank

Comment: Agreed with eric